# Pattern matching python - return multiple items from input in one go

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

Input:

```
A->(B, 1), (C, 2), (AKSDFSDF, 1231231) ...
```

Expected output:

```
[('A', 1, 2, 1231231)]
```

Cannot seem to get it to work. My code:

```
import re

pattern = r"([a-zA-z]+)->(.*)"
r = re.compile(pattern)

print r.findall("A->(B, 1), (C, 2), (AKSDFSDF, 1231231)")
>>> [('A', '(B, 1), (C, 2), (AKSDFSDF, 1231231)')]
```

That's close enough, but surely it's possible to extract exactly what I want?

I would have though this could work, but it doesnt:

```
pattern = r"([a-zA-z]+)->([\([a-zA-Z]+,([0-9]+)\)]*)"
```

That throws empty output (ie. `[]`), while this:

```
pattern = r"([a-zA-z]+)->((\([a-zA-Z]+,([0-9]+)\))*)"
>>> [('A', '', '', '')]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *positive lookahead assertion* to pick words starting with a word boundary `\b` and followed by `-` or `)`:

```
import re

s = 'A->(B, 1), (C, 2), (AKSDFSDF, 1231231)'
pattern = re.compile(r'\b\w+(?=-|\))')
print pattern.findall(s)
#['A', '1', '2', '1231231']
```

Try it out: https://repl.it/DqSe/0

Comment: @emihir0 Don't forget to accept if the answer helped :)

Comment: yes, sorry about that, you answered so quickly that the system wouldn't let me accept the answer yet and then I went off =). Just out of curiosity, why is the `\b` needed there? For my example it works even without it.